# What's the day in/out term for "i receive the payment"

Tags: translation

I'm looking for a good translation for what we, brazilians, call "dar baixa na conta 1234". Basically, it means that "i received the payment for the bill 1234"... I was thinking on "Inform Payment" but since i've never heard it on TV or other movies or other media, i'm second guessing myself... I need something succinct, that would fit a button on a website...

any better options?

**Edit 1:**
Let's put this in a context:
A customer enters the shop and says "I have an outstanding debt that I would like to pay".
The cashier would go in to the system, open the billings/financials module, load the debt amount, fill how the customer paid for it (cash, credit card, etc...), fill other infos and click the `B1` button.

Comment: What's the context? From your attempted translation it sounds like the website would be giving a confirmation the bill is paid, but then you say you want it on a button which sounds like you want the button to be clicked to pay the bill. Its very unclear.

Comment: Would 'Payment Received' or 'Paid' work?

Comment: Yhe closest thing i can think of is "invoice"?

Comment: On a button: “Record as Paid” or just “Received”

Answer (score 1):

I can't find one English word for this, but the phrase "got the money," although not very common, is fairly short and catchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a phrase that will let your customer know that you got their  payment, I think the most common one is

> Your payment has been received.

or

> We have received your payment.

That's a little formal, though.  If you want something shorter and more succinct, @Yosef Baskin's comment of **Payment Received.** is a good one.